# Why does my code run forever? its just a bunch of for loops with ints that are supposed to decrement?

Tags: java, for-loop

I wrote some code to print a scoreboard but it doesn't finish running. The scoreboard should look like this

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|\\ //|\\ //|\\ //|\\ //|\\ //|\\ //|\\ //|     |     |
| \V/ | \V/ | \V/ | \V/ | \V/ | \V/ | \V/ |     |     |
| /.\ | /.\ | /.\ | /.\ | /.\ | /.\ | /.\ |     |     |
|// \\|// \\|// \\|// \\|// \\|// \\|// \\|     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

but when I run it with a number for incorrectGuesses, it runs forever, and when I run it with zero for incorrect guesses, the scoreboard looks like this

```
+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+
```

This is my code:

```
public class PhraseGame {

    public static String drawScoreboard(int totalGuesses, int incorrectGuesses) {
        String result = "";
        String finalResult = "";

        for (int j = totalGuesses; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int g = incorrectGuesses; incorrectGuesses > 0; g--) {
                result = ("+-----");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            for (int i = totalGuesses - incorrectGuesses; i > 0; i--) {
                result = ("+--a---");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            result = ("+\n");
            finalResult += result;
        }
        for (int j = totalGuesses; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int g = incorrectGuesses; incorrectGuesses > 0; g--) {
                result = ("|\\\\ //");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            for (int h = totalGuesses - incorrectGuesses; h > 0; h--) {
                result = ("|     ");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            result = ("|\n");
            finalResult += result;
        }
        for (int j = totalGuesses; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int g = incorrectGuesses; incorrectGuesses > 0; g--) {
                result = ("| \\V/ ");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            for (int i = totalGuesses - incorrectGuesses; i > 0; i--) {
                result = ("|     ");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            result = ("|\n");
            finalResult += result;
        }
        for (int j = totalGuesses; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int g = incorrectGuesses; incorrectGuesses > 0; g--) {
                result = ("| /.\\ ");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            for (int i = totalGuesses - incorrectGuesses; i > 0; i--) {
                result = ("|     ");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            result = ("|\n");
            finalResult += result;
        }
        for (int j = totalGuesses; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int g = incorrectGuesses; incorrectGuesses > 0; g--) {
                result = ("|// \\\\");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            for (int i = totalGuesses - incorrectGuesses; i > 0; i--) {
                result = ("|     ");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            result = ("|\n");
            finalResult += result;
        }
        for (int j = totalGuesses; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int g = incorrectGuesses; incorrectGuesses > 0; g--) {
                result = ("+-----");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            for (int i = totalGuesses - incorrectGuesses; i > 0; i--) {
                result = ("+-----");
                finalResult += result;
            }
            result = ("+");
            finalResult += result;
        }
        result = "\n";
        finalResult += result;
        return finalResult;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(PhraseGame.drawScoreboard(4,2));
    }


}
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: If the answers below fix your stated problem, please accept one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping twice over the number of total guesses.

Your first layer of loops `for (int j = totalGuesses; j > 0; j--)` loops through the total number of guesses once while the second layer of loops with `incorrectGuesses` and `totalGuesses - incorrectGuesses` runs through the total number of guesses yet another time.

This means that with 3 total guesses, instead of printing thrice, you will print nine times! This is why each line of your output is printed multiple times.

In addition to that, as in @ScaryWombat's answer, your loop with `incorrectGuesses` is incorrect as it compares `incorrectGuesses > 0` instead of comparing `g > 0`.

Comment: @SkiMaskTheSlumpGod No problem. Do be careful with loops and try and run through your code manually as though you were the computer to spot mistakes like this.

Answer (score 3):

You are decrementing a value but not using it

```
for (int g = incorrectGuesses; incorrectGuesses > 0; g--) {
```

You should be comparing `g` to `0`

```
for (int g = incorrectGuesses; g > 0; g--) {
```

This is of course the same for all of your code